# Python Naming Convention for Variables that should be Classes

Tags: python, class, variables, naming-conventions

If I'm writing a function that takes a class as input, should it be any different than usual?

```
def func(convention_for_variables):
```

Or should it be aligned with the naming convention for classes to indicate that it should be a class?

```
def func(ClassVariable):
```

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use the first option:

```
def func(cls):
    ...
```

If in doubt, you can read PEP8 (link here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names). It's a programming style guide which covers topics such as Variable names and conventions